# Fetching value from nested optional elements in Java

Tags: java, option-type

Is there a more concise way of fetching the `orderLabel` information when it is present in an optional object which present under another optional object.

```
Optional<Order> maybeOrderInfo = getOrderInfo(); // API Call
Optional<String> orderLabel = maybeOrderInfo.isPresent()
  ? maybeOrderInfoPresent
    .get()
    .genericOrderInfo()
    .map(orderInfo -> orderInfo.get("orderLabel"))
    .or(() -> Optional.empty())
  : Optional.empty();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Optional#flatMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-).

```java
Optional<String> orderLabel = getOrderInfo().flatMap(Order::genericOrderInfo)
                               .map(orderInfo -> orderInfo.get("orderLabel"));
```